# Yaws is not loading yaws_dynopts module

Tags: erlang, yaws

I am running Yaws server version 2.0.2 with Erlang/OTP 18 [erts-7.3] on ubuntu 16.04 and installed it using apt. Now when i try to run [this](http://yaws.hyber.org/stream.yaws) example i get 
`undef yaws_dynopts random_seed`. I have verified that module yaws_dynopts is not loaded OR compiled.

error is:

```
{undef,[{yaws_dynopts,random_seed,[6885,441906,806568],[]},
        {m1,'-out/1-fun-0-',1,
            [{file,"/home/my_account/.yaws/yaws/default/m1.erl"},{line,16}]}]}
```

which corresponds to line in example:

```
yaws_dynopts:random_seed(erlang:phash(node(), 100000),
                                           erlang:phash(A2, A3),
                                           A3),
```

Do anyone have solution to this? And is it a bug?

Comment: What version of Erlang/OTP are you running? I don't know of any bugs reported against `yaws_dynopts`. Can you show the full error you're getting?

Comment: @SteveVinoski just done that

Comment: Thanks for the info. If you run `yaws -i` from a Linux shell, you get an interactive Erlang shell. Can you run the command `m(yaws_dynopts).` there and tell me what you see?

Comment: @SteveVinoski output is: `** exception error: undefined function yaws_dynopts:module_info/0
     in function  c:m/1 (c.erl, line 510)
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `l(yaws_dynopts).` also cause an error? I'm starting to believe whoever packaged your version of Yaws didn't do it correctly, leaving out this critical module. You should look to see if version 2.0.3 is available, or alternatively consider building your own [from source](https://github.com/klacke/yaws). We're currently at 2.0.4.

Comment: I also believe this is the case, I am missing .beam file for that module. Also where would be best place to report this as package bug?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know who packages Yaws for Ubuntu.

Comment: do you maybe know if http/2 support is comming in the future for yaws?

Comment: @KunaPrime: it's on a list of things to do but we don't currently have a plan for when it might be complete. We've had only a couple requests for it.